# Application will take a picture, but will not save it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, camera

I'm trying to take a picture and save it as a jpeg. For your information, if it helps, this is the third activity in the program that the user would access, and I'm hoping to save the picture into the data/user/0/com.example.app/appdata/inv/inv_pics file. Here's what I have:

```
    static String currentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File (MainActivity.path+"/com.example.app/appdata/inv/inv_pics");
        storageDir.mkdir();
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = Uri.parse((MainActivity.path+"/com.example.app/appdata/inv/inv_pics"));
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm loosely following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics). I've made the same  in my Manifest file, and have created the additional `file_paths` xml file. I had the Uri in the second method (`photoURI`) set up exactly how the method had it, with the arguments as it was in the tutorial. This was just producing errors, and so I basically hard-coded the file path to my app in there (which I know isn't "OOP") and now the code *almost* works.

When I run the app, and get to the activity, it opens the camera. That's great. I click the button to take the picture and the screen freezes for a second, but does not give me the "Retry" or "Ok" buttons at the bottom - the expected result.

Ideal function (again, for your information) :

Get to this activity. It opens a camera. (I am here.) When I take the picture, it would ask me "Retry" or "Ok" (as mentioned above.) If I click "Ok" the file name would be written to a text file where it would later be read in order to set the picture as the image on an `Image Button`.

Thanks in advance!

Edit :

I don't believe it's a permissions problem, a) I have the permissions declared in the Manifest, and b) the first method does actually create the file, it's just blank, which lets me know the code runs until at least the `photoFile = createImageFile();` in the second method.

Since I know you'll probably ask, here's the errors it gives me when I try to use the code provided by the tutorial:

````
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 4700
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.app/files/Pictures/JPEG_20191201_235937_8382995102420149896.jpg
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
        at com.erthad.boutique.InventoryActivity2.dispatchTakePictureIntent(InventoryActivity2.java:59)
        at com.erthad.boutique.InventoryActivity2.access$000(InventoryActivity2.java:21)
        at com.erthad.boutique.InventoryActivity2$1.onClick(InventoryActivity2.java:82)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7341)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7307)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27796)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)```
````

Comment: The String MainActivity.path is simply the root path for the application. (data/user/0)

Comment: maybe you dont have the right permissions?

Comment: I thought so at first, but then I checked the dir itself. Check my edit.

Comment: why you want to safe the picure at the same place like the application?

Comment: Because the image needs to be used to set the `src` for an Image Button. I figured that would be the best way to do it.

Comment: but if you run your app on a mobile device that won't work try to save it in the internal storage

Comment: Also, just for the sake of my curiosity, the `path` of `File photoFile` and the `path` in `file_paths.xml` both read `data/user/0/XXX` but the error tells me the `uri` is `data/data/XXX`. Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? And how would I save it to internal storage properly? Using the method from the tutorial, it tries to save it to `storage/emulated`, which I don't have access to. Can I just ask for permission to internal storage in my manifest and it would work?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came to me after reading into DoFlamingo's comments and answers, so partial credit to him.

The problem was in fact that I was not writing to the right storage. But the solution was something I didn't even think of initially. The [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) was actually spot on. I tried editing the directory in the `paths.xml` file to point to a directory I was using when I began writing the code (namely `data/data/user/0/com.example.app/appdata/inv/inv_pics`) when it should have pointed to exactly what DoFlamingo was saying - and the tutorial (namely `storage/emulated/XXX`).

So, here's to making things a lot more complicated then they needed to be. I'll leave the post up in case it helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

Use Base64 to get the picture as a String:

Read from Internal

```
public StringBuilder fromInternal(String filename) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(filename);
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb;
    }
```

Save file to Internal:

```
    public void toInternal(String data,String sFileName){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+sFileName);
        byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(bytes);
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

and add this permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: decode you picture with base64. the you have a string witch represents the picture.

Comment: then use the toInternal()-function to save the gernatet string on the internal storage